# Cannot find python 3.5.x interpreter using .msi extension

Tags: python, python-2.7, ide, pycharm, python-3.5

I'm new to stack overflow. I was wondering if anybody knew if there was a .msi package for a python interpreter for python 3.5, I'm teaching a basic python class and wanted to be prepared for when it starts in a few weeks. There is a .msi packaged interpreter for 2.7 python on the official python.org downloads page but not 3.5 it seems. I am trying to use the interpreter in the community PyCharm IDE because I'm assuming most of the students will be using windows, not Linux (like I'm using). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Python 3.4.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-344/) was released python.org stopped providing MSI installers for their Windows releases. Web-based, exectuable, and zipped installers are now provided for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows releases. I'm not sure what the reason for this switch was, but an exectuable will install Python just fine. You can find Python 3.5.2 Windows executable installer at the bottom of [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/).

All Python installs come with a Python interpreter. Make sure you select to add Python to your PATH during the install process. After Python finishes installing, open a Command Prompt, and type `python` to access the Python interpreter.

Comment: You don't need to add python to the path anymore.  [The PyLauncher option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#installation-steps) puts py.exe in the %SystemRoot%, which is already in the path.  It  [makes it easy](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) to run multiple Python versions side-by-side (and is shorter to type).